# jenkins job DSL from remote SCM

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-job-dsl

I created a job DSL script for my projects to run on jenkins, the job cotains tokens and secrets. Hence, i used a bitbucket as my remote SCM. and stored the tokens as secrets. the question is how to make jenkins get the values of secrets when i run it via jenkins, or if there's a method to run directly via bitbucket pipelines ?

another method is to store the secrets in jenkins as credentials and retreive them during execution. but idk really how to do so
the steps is as follows:

def x = {"service": "servicetoken", "service":"servicetoken"}

for service,token in x:
do x
do y

i tried to add them as plain text in the first release of my job DSL (before i include it in SCM) and worked but the secret is in the method of how to do this in a secure way

Comment: You want to use the credentials during the job creation or within the created job?

Comment: @Matthias
i want to use it during job creation i use it to create multibranch pipeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use credentials within a pipeline you can use the credentials binding (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/):

```
withCredentials([usernameColonPassword(credentialsId: 'mylogin', variable: 'USERPASS')]) { ... }
```

If you then want to use it in your JobDSL, make sure to specify your JobDSL code within GStrings ("-double quotes).

```
"""
job('example') {
  steps {
    batchFile(echo $USERPASS >secret.txt)
  }
}
"""
```

---

In case you are trying to resolve those variables within aJobDSL script file, rather than hard coded into your pipeline, you could do something like this:

```
def dslScripts = findFiles(glob: 'job-dsl/*.groovy')
dslScripts.each {
    def scriptContent = readFile(it.path)
    def interpolatedScript = evaluate("return \"\"\"${scriptContent}\"\"\"")
    
    jobDsl scriptText: interpolatedScript, sandbox: true
}
```

Comment: thanks, the solution was near to what I want so it inspired me the solution,  i created the job dsl to create folders, inside folders multi-branch pipelines. and to pass the secrets values i added it as env during execution using the plugin you provided, thanks in the end I appreciate that.